# im getting a error message parse error: syntax error, unexpected "

Tags: php

I get this error can someone help please

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\Users\packardbell\Desktop\hdd\htdocs\qr\index.php on line 217

this is line 217

```
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];

$password = $_REQUEST['pass'];

$good=0;

if(isset($username) && isset($password))
```

Comment: Can you show us the line before this?

Comment: The problem is not on line 217, but one of the lines before it.  Somewhere you are not closing a quote.

Comment: BTW, you should check with `if( isset( $_REQUEST['username'], $_REQUEST['pass']) )`, otherwise the notice will still be thrown if those aren't set.

Comment: this the code before that          $db_selected = mysql_select_db('qrcodes');
      if(!$db_selected)
      {
        die ('cant\'t connect :' . mysqlerror());
      }
  }
  else
  {
 this is line 217 $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
  $password = $_REQUEST['pass'];

Comment: If what you posted as your actual code in your comment above here, you're missing a closing brace `}` and one too many after `mysqlerror());` @user3490113

Comment: Please update your code accordingly, this doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 2):

If what you are using being your actual code that you posted [**in a comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816318/im-getting-a-error-message-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected/22816713#comment34797389_22816318), you're missing a closing brace `}` and one too many after `mysqlerror());` <= *Consult "footnotes" about this.*

Your code from a comment:

```
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('qrcodes'); 
if(!$db_selected) { 
die ('cant\'t connect :' . mysqlerror()); 
} } 
else { this is line 217 $username = $_REQUEST['username']; $password = $_REQUEST['pass'];
```

Sidenote: You have `mysqlerror` which should read as `mysql_error` as per [**the manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

New code:

```
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('qrcodes'); 
if(!$db_selected) {
die ('cant\'t connect :' . mysql_error());
} 
else
{
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = $_REQUEST['pass'];
}
```

---

**Footnotes:**

I agree with [Andy Lester's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816318/im-getting-a-error-message-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected#comment34797021_22816318) in regards to actual errors coming from a line or lines further above. Error messages pointing to a certain line number, doesn't necessarily mean it's on "that" line.

Showing full code will take the guesswork out of things, however from what you did post in your comment, it's a bracing mismatch issue, and using `mysqlerror` instead of `mysql_error` (*you forgot the underscore between `mysql` and `error`*) would have provided more information which failed in doing so because of it.

---

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.